# Must I have a return statement in a method when I already have it in the if statement?

Tags: java

I got a function like below:

```
public double getCost(String bookName)
{
    if(bookName.equals(arrayOfBook[2]))
    {
        return arrayOfCost[2];
    }
}
```

arrayOfCost is an array of double. So I already have a statement to return double value here. But the compiler still says I am missing return statement in this function. That's why?

Comment: but what if bookName is not equal to arrayOfBook[2] ? What should be returned?

Comment: Yes, you must have a return statement along each possible path to exit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you do need a return statement (in fact, the compiler tells you so). This is because your method *must* return something regardless of the condition. In other words, your program needs to specify what happens when the condition is `false`. For example, you could return a zero, an infinity, a "not a number" constant, et cetera.

The only exception is `void` methods: they do not require a return statement at the end, and you are allowed to have `return`s in other branches.

Comment: If I add an statement "return 0" out of the if statement, will this method return 2 values when the if is true?

Comment: @user3368506 No, a method cannot return two values - it will return one or the other, depending on what branch it takes. When the condition is true, `arrayOfCost[2]` will be returned. When the condition is false, zero will be returned.

Answer (score 2):

What if the if statement is false? In this situation nothing is returned, which is not allowed.

Your code must be written so that the method returns something in *all* possible cases, or if it can't return something because of some exceptional event, then it must throw an exception.

An example of the latter:

```
public Bar checkFoo() throws FooException {
   if (baz) {
      return new Bar();
   }  else {
      throw new FooException("baz was false");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the if doesn't succeeds there will not be a return.

You need atleast to put it it the else

```
public double getCost(String bookName)
{
    if(bookName.equals(arrayOfBook[2]))
    {
        return arrayOfCost[2];
    }
    else return -1;

}
```

Comment: @user3368506 ,you don't need to say thank you in all of the answers ,just click the "tick" button next to the answer you want to accept and if you want upvote other helpful awnsers too.